# Delay after prepending elements to a list and scroll to same scrolling view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

When you scroll to some position in the list and press "Space", new elements are prepended to the list. The code intention is to stay in the same scrolling view as before the user press "Space." Items are loaded and for some miliseconds, scroll view is in top of new prepended items and then scroll to saved previous scroll view. I want to make it instantly, without that miliseconds delay that is annoying for user.

Is it possible to get it?

**CODE:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const listRefs = useRef({});
  const scrollRef = useRef();
  const oldListHeight = useRef();

  const generateId = (length) => {
    let result = "";
    const characters =
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
  };

  const generateList = () => {
    const html = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 20; i++) {
      const id = generateId(15);

      listRefs.current[id] = React.createRef();
      html.push(
        <li ref={listRefs[id]} key={id}>
          {id}
        </li>
      );
    }

    return html;
  };

  const [htmlList, setHtmlList] = useState(generateList());

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const listHeightDiff =
        scrollRef.current.scrollHeight - oldListHeight.current;
      scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
        top: scrollRef.current.scrollTop + listHeightDiff
      });
    }, 0);
  }, [htmlList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown, false);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown, false);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === " ") {
      oldListHeight.current = scrollRef.current.scrollHeight;
      setHtmlList((htmlList) => [generateList(), ...htmlList]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={scrollRef} className="wrapper">
        <ul>{htmlList}</ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**PLAYGROUND:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-antonelli-wkvvd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Are you trying to say that, the `htmlList` loads everything again and again and causing a small delay as you keep adding more and more stuff?

Comment: Enter to Playground, press "Space Key" several times to create a large scrollable list. Then scroll to one position and press "Space Key". You will see like a delay where new list is charged and then scroll to last view. It's not instantly and I want to have same result without that mini delay.

Comment: To be honest it works like a charm. I can't reproduce the issue that you're having even when trying in your CodeSandbox

Comment: I've created a video to show you the problem. check the little delay when adding new list: https://files.fm/f/8wd9k4h38

Comment: Check the updated code and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the issue,

Your `setHtmlList((htmlList) => [generateList(), ...htmlList]);`

generateList() returns an array so your array becomes [[some ids],oldids],

It becomes an array of arrays and React re-renders everything. What you need is [new ids,old ids].

To fix it I had to change the above line to

`setHtmlList((htmlList) => [...generateList(), ...htmlList]);`

Note the spread operator on `generateList()`. That will make the array flat and React can manage the rest.

Updated code,

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-cherry-6hxyo?file=/src/App.js:1572-1633